# Using kwargs To control the flow inside the method

Tags: python, methods, keyword-argument

I am trying to write a method inside a class where the same method could be used for an endpoint whose parameters change based on year/month/day. Year is mandatory parameter while month/day are optional. Is there a mechanism to track the number of args passed and control flow inside the method?

```
 # Global var
URL = 'http://posts/archive/'


# trying to use *kwargs for mn and day. year is required/positional.
get_records_arch(year, mn, dy):

if year only is passed:
    API_ENDPOINT = 'http://posts/archive/{year}/'.format(year=YEAR)
else if 'year and mn' are passed:
    API_ENDPOINT = 'http://posts/archive/{year}/{month}/'.format(year=YEAR, month=MON)
else
    API_ENDPOINT = 'http://posts/archive/{year}/{month}/{day}/'.format(year=YEAR, month=MON, day=DAY)
```

Comment: `def get_records_arch(year, mn=None, dy=None):` then test for `None` seems the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

Give `mn` and `dy` default values of `None`, then check if each has a non-`None` value before trying to use them.  Note that `dy` is completely ignored unless `mn` is non-`None`.

```
def get_records_arch(year, mn=None, dy=None):
    API_ENDPOINT = 'http://posts/archive/{}/'.format(year)
    if mn is not None:
        API_ENDPOINT += '{}/'.format(mn)
        if dy is not None:
            API_ENDPOINT += '{}/'.format(dy)

    ...
```